# How to generate rectangular honeycomb network

Tags: python, r, igraph, graph-theory

How would one go about generating a graph-like object (in R or Python) representing a regular rectangular network of connected hexagons, like in the following image:

[image]

Vertices at the "center" of the graph should each have 6 edges, and vertices at the "sides" of the graph should have either 2, 3 or 5 edges.

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself? Any code or plans / outline of a possible method? And will it be more than just a graphical representation?

Comment: I have no idea of a possible approach unfortunately. I am not particularly interested in a graphical representation; I will need the graph-like object to run some simulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a grid of adjacency sets representing the indices of the cells each individual cell is connected with:

```
class HexGraph:
    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.cells = [[set() for c in range(self.cols)] for r in range(self.rows)]
        self.build_connections()

    def build_connections(self):
        offsets = (((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1)),
                   ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (1, 1)))
        for rdx, line in enumerate(self.cells):
            for cdx, cell in enumerate(line):
                for dr, dc in offsets[rdx % 2]:
                    r = rdx + dr
                    c = cdx + dc
                    if r >= 0 and r < self.rows and c >= 0 and c < self.cols:
                        cell.add((r, c))

    def __str__(self):
        result = []
        for line in self.cells:
            res = ''
            for cell in line:
                res += str(cell) + ', '
            result.append(res)
        return '\n'.join(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    g = HexGraph(5, 4)
    print(g)
```

#### output:

```
{(0, 1), (1, 0)}, {(0, 2), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)}, {(1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 1), (1, 1)}, {(1, 2), (1, 3), (0, 2)}, 
{(0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 1)}, {(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 0), (0, 2)}, {(1, 3), (0, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (1, 1)}, {(1, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3)}, 
{(3, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1)}, {(3, 0), (3, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)}, {(1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1)}, {(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2)}, 
{(3, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0), (4, 1), (4, 0)}, {(3, 2), (3, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 2), (4, 1)}, {(3, 3), (3, 1), (2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 2), (4, 2)}, {(3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 3)}, 
{(3, 0), (4, 1)}, {(3, 0), (4, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0)}, {(3, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3)}, {(4, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)},
```

It corresponds to the connections between nodes in the image you posted, with each second row pulled a bit to the left to align vertically with the nodes directly above & under it.

[image]

[image]

Please pardon the poor quality drawing.